# can't set profile photo with ms graph

Tags: java, groovy, microsoft-graph-api

I tried the following:

```
filePath = sourcePath + "ash.jpg";

byte[] fileContent = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(filePath));
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);

imagePayload = HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(encodedString)

def url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<myuser>/photo/$value';

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                        .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                        .build();

HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                      .uri(URI.create(url))
                      .method("PUT",imagePayload)
                      .header("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
                      .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                      .build();
```

the return keeps telling me :

> An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., The file you
> chose isn't an image. Please choose a different file.

I guess that the payload is wrong, but what does he expect exactly ? the MS Graph documentation states that it should the binary represetation of the jpeg image

with the following:

```
filePath = sourcePath + "ash.jpg";

file = new File(filePath);

BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", b);

byte[] jpgByteArray = b.toByteArray();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte by : jpgByteArray)
    sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(by & 0xFF));

imagePayloadAsString = sb.toString();

imagePayload = HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(imagePayloadAsString)
```

I get the binary string with Os and 1s but the webservice still says that my file is not an image. I must confess that I'm confused

Comment: Try isolating the issue by using POSTMAN/MS Graph Explorer and use the same payload to see if it works for you or not.

Comment: Yes, this endpoint takes the raw image as input, not a base64 encoded version. From the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http In the request body, include the binary data of the photo in the request body.

Comment: Let me post the code in answer, as it doesn't fit it here. So that you can give a try.

Comment: regarding the first comment : it works in Postman but I cannot set exactly the same payload since this is solved using the GUI : you browse an image and postman do the conversion for you

Comment: I found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181102/uploading-profile-photo-from-microsoft-graph-explorer
it says : "Given that you need to read the file into memory in order to include it in the body, I'm not quite sure this would work with Explorer.". How should I serialize the data so that it comes as a binary string ?

Comment: If it works for POSTMAN (you can ignore the Microsoft Graph Explorer) then its good. I know you need to construct the same payload as the Graph API looks for.

Comment: that's correct. then the question is : what payload is used by postman when setting "binary" in the payload...

Comment: I watched the call from postman using wireshark and it shows that the payload is really a JPEG File Interchange Format... At which moment does postman convert it as "raw". Is this possible that I should not encode it at all (i.e. put the output of `new File("myimage.jpg")`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it! what the ms graph service awaits is just the file itself (with the header image/jpeg). So this way I managed to upload the photo:

```
file = new File(filePath);

imagePayload = HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofFile(file.toPath())
```

as Dev stated, no need to convert it using base64

Answer (score 0):

This endpoint takes the raw image as input, not a base64 encoded version. Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). In the request body, include the binary data of the photo in the request body.

I see that you're using HTTPClient. I would do like the following:

Code snippet:

```js
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    var authResult = await AuthenticationHelper.Current.GetAccessTokenAsync();
    if (authResult.Status != AuthenticationStatus.Success)
        return;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);
    Uri userPhotoEndpoint = new Uri(AuthenticationHelper.GraphEndpointId + "users/" + userIdentifier + "/Photo/$value");
    StreamContent content = new StreamContent(image);
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync(userPhotoEndpoint, content))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response! is this code java or C# ? I don't have any StreamContent class available in groovy/java

Comment: The code is C# and without using Graph SDK, rather i used HTTPClient, as i thought it might help you.